# Can't figure out the system for "approve post once 10 users like it"

Tags: php, mysql, voting

I have a voting system for articles. Articles are stored in 'stories' table and all votes are stored in 'votes' table. id in 'stories' table is equal to item_name in 'votes' table (therefore each vote is related to article with item_name).

I want to make it so when sum of votes gets to 10 it updates 'showing' field in 'stories' table to value of "1".

Here is a query I use to insert votes into database now (I was thinking to add something to it or create another query to sum vote_values of article user is voting on and see if they are > 10 if yes set showing = 1) :

```
$q = "INSERT INTO {$this->votes_table} (`vote_value`, `item_name`, `ip`) VALUES({$dir}, '{$story_id}', '{$ip}')";
```

Here is my database structure:

**Stories table**

[image]

---

**Votes table**

[image]

Comment: Might be a good case for a trigger here...

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm new to php, what is a trigger?

Comment: Instead of storing a id [int(11)] in the item_name [varhcar(255)] make a foreign key in Votes named story_id [int(11)] and use piotrekkr's SQL statement modified for this change.

Comment: Trigger is database logic that occurs when a certain event is performed.  So when an insert occurs on the Votes table you could fire some logic to update the Stories.showing column when the count is >= 10.  I like to avoid triggers when business logic, as in your case, dictates that the code should live in the domain.

Comment: I'm not talking about anything PHP related, I'm talking about [MySQL triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html), which is a sequence of SQL statements that is executed when certain events occur. So you would create a trigger that happens every time you insert a row into the `votes` table, which performs a select to see if there are >= 10 votes, and if there are, update the `stories` table. Basically what I'm saying is get MySQL to do it for you, so you can keep your PHP tidy and not have to worry about the extra queries.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_ids SELECT s.id
FROM stories s 
JOIN votes v ON v.item_name = s.id 
WHERE s.showing != 1
GROUP BY s.id 
HAVING SUM(v.vote_value) >= 10;

UPDATE stories SET showing = 1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tmp_ids)
```

// EDIT version on every vote

```
UPDATE stories s 
SET s.showing = IF((SELECT SUM(vote_value) FROM votes WHERE item_name = ?) >= 10, 1, 0)
WHERE s.id = ?
```

Comment: Alright, by this I can select articles that have vote value >=10, but How will I set showing=1 ?

Comment: I've added where condition not to select as sum votes for stories that already have showing = 1

Comment: So when a vote is cast, execute the above SQL.  When the result is >= 10 update the `Stories` table for the voted on item's `showing` column to 1.  If a story is already showing you do need to execute the above SQL unless you also allow down votes (in which case you'll need execute it every time to catch edge cases).

Comment: ... the revised SQL code will not scale horizontally if you execute it every time someone votes.  As the number of stories and votes increase, the amount of time necessary to case a vote increases.

Comment: No it's more like cron job sql. If you want to update showing on every vote you could do `UPDATE stories s SET s.showing = 1 WHERE s.id = ? AND (SELECT SUM(vote_value) FROM votes WHERE item_name = s.id) >= 10`

Comment: So basically I should add your code after my INSERT query that I mentioned in the question correct? Coz I tested it now didn't work, I'm not sure if I'm using it right though.

Comment: @piotrekkr Ou, is it a better idea to use a cron job for this? I was thinking about it before, but I thought that it will take up a lot of server resources to go through all votes stored in database. For me a cron job solution seems as easier and more efficient. But it would be good so it only looks at posts that have showing=0 and ignores ones with showing=1, so less server resources are taken.

Comment: No you do not use a cron job for something like this.  You do if you've got an in-memory cache and you want to replicate your values to the database for the next memory cache flush but if you're not building to scale for thousands of concurrent users its not something you need to worry about right now.

Comment: No if you don't have heavy load or very big database on your site, you don't need to use cron / cache for this. Look at my post again I've added other type of query you can execute after vote.